# Align 3 dots icon on Top in ListItem in React Native Elements

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-elements

In screen shot shown how to place the 3 dots icon in top right side right now its in center.

Using https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/listitem.html

Sample Code

```
<ListItem
  containerStyle={styles.containerStyle}
  title={this.getTitleView(data)}
  subtitle={this.getAddressView(data)}
  leftElement={this.getAvatarView(data)}
  rightElement={<Icon type="material" color="#C8C8C8" name="more-vert" />}
  />
```

Basically I want the `rightElement` to be placed on **top** instead of **center**

[image: Sampe Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the icon to move up, but I wasn't able to make it move even more to the right.

To actually get the `<Icon>` to align to the top corner add the `containerStyle` prop to it and use the `alignSelf: 'flex-start'` style, just like this:

```js
rightElement={<Icon containerStyle={{ alignSelf: 'flex-start' }} type="material" color="#C8C8C8" name="more-vert" />
```

It should look like this image.

[image]

Hope this helps.